# How Node JS Map Of Values Adds Up to K

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

Given a list of numbers `const arr = [{ key1: 10 }, { key2: 5 }, { key3: 7 }, { key4: 17 }];`and a number k say `const k = 17;`, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k. For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k = 17, we should return True, since 10 + 7 =17.

Wrote below code using `key,values` in Map,but seems not able to get the solution,can anyone suggest what code change is needed below ,want to solve especially using `Maps`

```
const arr = [{ key1: 10 }, { key2: 5 }, { key3: 7 }, { key4: 17 }];
const k = 17;
let addInput = new Map(arr.flatMap((x) => Object.entries(x)));

addInput.forEach((v) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < addInput.size; i++) {
    if (v != addInput[i]) {
      if (addInput[i] + v == k) {
        console.log(`${v} + ${addInput[i]} = ${k} (true)`);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is in the `addInput` variable? You probably want something else in there. You want a different function in place of `Object.entries(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is unclear with your code:
You should use `Set` to remove duplicate not `Map` and you should use `map` operator to extract the values from the object, you also can't access map operator with number index like array.

```js
const arr = [{ key1: 10 }, { key2: 5 }, { key3: 7 }, { key4: 17 }];
const k = 17;
// using set to remove duplicate
let valueSet = new Set(arr.flatMap((x) => Object.values(x)));

// using array to iterate easily, convert by destruturing
let valueArray = [...valueSet];

valueArray.forEach((v1, i1) => {
  for (let i2 = i1 + 1 ; i2 < valueArray.length; i2++) {
      if ((v1 + valueArray[i2]) === k) {
        console.log(`${v1} + ${valueArray[i2]} = ${k} (true)`);
      }
  }
});
```